# How to connect PyQt signal to external function

Tags: python, windows, file, pyqt

How does one connect a pyqt button signal in one file, to a function in another python file? I've tried various things, but nothing seems to work.
This is the first file:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow
from MainUIFile import Ui_Main
from pythonfile import myOutsideFunction
class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_file):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(myOutsideFunction())
```

The second file that is called by the first:

```
def myOutsideFunction(self):
    # Do some stuff here
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you solve it finally ?

Comment: I also had the same issue. I was able to fix it by putting the function in a mixin and make `MainWindow` inherit from the mixin (e.g. `class MainWindow(QMainWindow, EventsMixin)`)

Answer (score 2):

You are currently making a call to `myOutsideFunction` and passing the result to the `connect` function, which expects a callable as an argument.

Remove the parenthesis from `myOutsideFunction` in the connect call

```
self.btn.clicked.connect(myOutsideFunction)
```

Comment: I was actually already doing .connect(myOutsideFunction) without parenthesis before I posted this without any luck. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @user3419537. Note that `myOutsideFunction` has a `self` argument. If that's intentional, it might explain what the other errors were...

Answer (score 1):

What is the importance of connecting to a function outside of your code?  Could you not just do something like this:

```
def myOutsideFunction(a,b,c,d):
    #process variables/objects a,b,c,d as you wish
    return answer

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow
from MainUIFile import Ui_Main
from pythonfile import myOutsideFunction
class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_file):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.pressed_the_button())
        #initialize your variables/objects for your outside function if need be

    def pressed_the_button(self):
        answer_from_outside_function = myOutsideFunction(self.a,self.b,self.c,self.d)
        # run whatever you need to here...
```

Comment: This is not a solution - it has exactly the same problem as the code in the question.

Comment: @ekhumoro how do you figure?  We have no indication as to what the actual failure is.  The question was how to connect a button to an outside function.  This is one way to do that.  Presumably one would pass other variables/objects into that outside function which could be done by defining them in the __init__ or other places in the code.  I've edited my answer to be more descriptive.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't work, because it attempts to pass the return value of a callable to `connect`, rather than the callable object itself. Your code makes exactly the same mistake. The [other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40027367/984421) already covered this point.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and I think it comes from the fact that the `myOutsideFunction` live in a different thread than the GUI's one, or something like that. It seems that the function you want to connect to the signal has to be an attribute of your class `MainWindow`, or a function of an object created from the same thread as the GUI.